# change / replace specific part of url inside a parsed table

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

I want to parse a table via simple_html_dom. So far so good. Now I want to change all links inside the table cells. They currently end with ".htm" and should be changed to ".php", so the links direct to the same filename, but another filetype. Since the content of the source file is continuously changing, it must work independently of the file name.

Example:

```
<td><a href="www.website.com/site1.htm" ... --> <td><a href="www.website.com/site1.php"
```

This is current code:

```
// Download simple_html_dom.php first from http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
// Get the contents of the HTML document either using cURL, a crawling
// framework, or use the provided file_get_html() function.
$html = file_get_html('mywebsite/example.htm');


// Table 1
    $table = $html->find('table', 1);
    $rowData = array();

    foreach($table->find('tr') as $row) {
        // initialize array to store the cell data from each row
        $flight = array();
        foreach($row->find('td') as $cell) {
            // push the cell's text to the array
            $flight[] = $cell->innertext;
        }
        foreach($row->find('th') as $cell) {
            // push the cell's text to the array
            $flight[] = $cell->innertext;
        }
        $rowData[] = $flight;
    }
    foreach ($rowData as $row => $tr) {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach ($tr as $td)
            echo '<td>' . $td .'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
```

The source looks like:

```
    table><hr>
<tr><th>po</th><th>player</th><th>age</th><th>2ga</th><th>2g%</th><th>fta</th><th>ft%</th><th>3ga</th><th>3g%</th><th>orb</th><th>drb</th><th>ast</th><th>stl</th><th>to</th><th>blk</th><th>o-o</th><th>d-o</th><th>p-o</th><th>t-o</th><th>o-d</th><th>d-d</th><th>p-d</th><th>t-d</th></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp>PG</td><td CLASS=tdp><a href="JamesHarden7.htm">James Harden                    </a></td><td>27</td><td>48</td><td>53</td><td>95</td><td>85</td><td>85</td><td>35</td><td>20</td><td>59</td><td>99</td><td>57</td><td>1</td><td>12</td><td>4</td><td>9</td><td>7</td><td>9</td><td>8</td><td>6</td><td>5</td><td>7</td></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp>PG</td><td CLASS=tdp><a href="TerryRozier1.htm">Terry Rozier                    </a></td><td>22</td><td>31</td><td>41</td><td>15</td><td>77</td><td>43</td><td>32</td><td>18</td><td>42</td><td>31</td><td>46</td><td>79</td><td>8</td><td>5</td><td>4</td><td>4</td><td>2</td><td>6</td><td>5</td><td>4</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp>SG</td><td CLASS=tdp><a href="DannyGreen6.htm">Danny Green  

and so on...
```

Comment: Is your url.html in php variable ? Where is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `find("td a")` to get the anchors for your example.

Then you could use a `foreach` to loop over the results and replace the last 3 characters of the `href` property with `php` using for example [substr_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php)

```
$html = <<<HTML
 <table><hr>
<tr><th>po</th><th>player</th><th>age</th><th>2ga</th><th>2g%</th><th>fta</th><th>ft%</th><th>3ga</th><th>3g%</th><th>orb</th><th>drb</th><th>ast</th><th>stl</th><th>to</th><th>blk</th><th>o-o</th><th>d-o</th><th>p-o</th><th>t-o</th><th>o-d</th><th>d-d</th><th>p-d</th><th>t-d</th></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp>PG</td><td CLASS=tdp><a href="JamesHarden7.htm">James Harden                    </a></td><td>27</td><td>48</td><td>53</td><td>95</td><td>85</td><td>85</td><td>35</td><td>20</td><td>59</td><td>99</td><td>57</td><td>1</td><td>12</td><td>4</td><td>9</td><td>7</td><td>9</td><td>8</td><td>6</td><td>5</td><td>7</td></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp>PG</td><td CLASS=tdp><a href="TerryRozier1.htm">Terry Rozier                    </a></td><td>22</td><td>31</td><td>41</td><td>15</td><td>77</td><td>43</td><td>32</td><td>18</td><td>42</td><td>31</td><td>46</td><td>79</td><td>8</td><td>5</td><td>4</td><td>4</td><td>2</td><td>6</td><td>5</td><td>4</td><td>6</td></tr>
</table>
HTML;

$html = str_get_html($html);

foreach ($html->find("td a") as $a) {
    $a->href = substr_replace($a->href, 'php', -3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use DOMDocument instead and use XPath to find any reference to your website.  This code loads the HTML and will look for *any* href attribute which has the website as part of the URL.  It then changes the 
htm extension to php.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$links = $xp->query("//@href[contains(.,'www.website.com')]");
foreach ( $links as $href )    {
    $href->nodeValue = str_replace(".htm", ".php", $href->nodeValue);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```